# Retrieve the compilation options for octave

Tags: octave, configure

Is there any simple way to retrieve the compilation options for octave ?

Something similar to python:

```
import distutils.sysconfig
print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('CONFIG_ARGS'))
>>> '--enable-shared' '--enable-ipv6' '--with-ensurepip=no' <...>
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

octave_config_info () is very chatty. For example the configure options as you asked on my system:

```
octave:1> octave_config_info().config_opts 
ans = '--disable-gui'
```

EDIT: as carandraug has pointed out "octave_config_info()" has been deprecated for 4.2. You can see a discussion on the maintainers mailinglist here: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/quot-features-quot-problems-td4675361.html

Comment: I would add that `octave_config_info` has been deprecated for Octave 4.2